# NodeMCU current consumption in all modes

Tags: nodemcu

I am using NodeMCU for my project.I wanted to know how much current it takes in its all modes like sleep mode,deep sleep mode and also in its wifi modes like station and access point mode.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: have you checked the datasheet?

Comment: count the consumption of the USB chip too